# Using PHP to add data to a SQL Table and how to show errors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Updated Problem:
I'm trying to use PHP to add information into a SQL table if there is no errors, but I am not sure how to get it to fully working so that it'll show the errors and such. Where do I put the PHP code? Also where what language would I use to display the errors?

Updated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>TheQuantumBros</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MainStyles.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<style type="text/css">
.style2 {
font-size: xx-large;
color: white;
}
.style3 {
font-size: xx-large;
color: #008000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style=";background-image:url('bg_wallpaper_black.jpg');margin:0;padding-top:0;">
<div id="topBar" class="topBar">
    <h1 id="title" class="title">
        <img src="TheQuantumBros3.png" alt="" style="padding-right:5px" />
        TheQuantumBros
        <img src="TheQuantumBros3.png" alt="" style="padding-left:5px"/>
    </h1>
</div>

<div id="topDiv" class="topDiv" style="height:200px">
    <div id="topDivFrame" class="topDivFrame" style="background-image:url('TheQuantumBros2.png');height:200px"></div>
</div>

<div id="menuBar" class="menuBar">
    <button name="homeButton" class="menuButton1" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://www.tqbtest.comlu.com/'">Home</button>
    <button name="forumsButton" class="menuButton2">Forums</button>
    <button name="bfButton" class="menuButton2">BF P4F</button>
    <button name="mcButton" class="menuButton2">Minecraft</button>
    <button name="applyButton" class="menuButton2">Applications</button>
    <button name="infoButton" class="menuButton2">About Us</button>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:150px;margin-top: 5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center">
    <div style="width:75%;height:100%;text-align:center">
        <span style="width:75%;height:10%;margin-right:15%;margin-left:45%;text-align:center" class="style2">TheQuantumBros Registration</span>
        <form method="post" action="register.php" style="height:100%;width:100%;text-align:center">

            <span class="registrationText">First Name:</span>
            <input name="firstname" type="text" class="registrationInput"/>

            <span class="registrationText">Last Name:</span>
            <input name="lastname" type="text" class="registrationInput"/>

            <span class="registrationText">Username:</span>
            <input name="username" type="text" class="registrationInput"/>

            <span class="registrationText">Email</span>
            <input name="email" type="text" class="registrationInput"/>

            <span class="registrationText">Password</span>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="registrationInput"/>

            <span class="registrationText">Retype Password:</span>
            <input name="password2" type="password" class="registrationInput"/>

            <span class="registrationText">Region</span>
            <select name="region" class="registrationInput">
                <option>North America</option>
                <option>South America</option>
                <option>Europe</option>
                <option>Asia</option>
                <option>Africa</option>
                <option>Australia</option>
            </select>

            <span style="width:25%"></span>
            <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" class="registrationSubmit"/>
            <span class="notFilled" id="notFilled">*Please fill in all the fields.</span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated PHP:

```
    $sql="SELECT username, email FROM Profiles";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if($result === false){
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $rows[] = $row;

            foreach ($rows as $row) {

                if($row['username'] == $_POST['username'] || $row['email'] == $_POST['email']){
                   //Error: "Username or Email already in use"
                }else {
                   if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']){
                       if (strpos($_POST['email'],'@') !== false) {
                           //INSERT INTO code?
                       }else{
                          //Error: "Please enter a valid email."
                       }
                   }else{
                      //Error: "Passwords do not match."
                   }
                }
            }
        mysqli_close($con);
        }
    }
}else{
   //Error code: "Please fill in all fields"
}
?>
```

Comment: Why you are invloving PHP for jquery echo?

Comment: Why are you adding the script as php?
In any case, try using $("#notFilled").hide() and .show()

Comment: Firstly, your echoing JS outside of the `<html>` which is never good. Secondly you haven't wrapped your JS in a ready call `jQuery(function() {...code...});`. Finally, why are you using PHP to echo javascript that changes CSS? Why not just use CSS?

Comment: The user probably has some other php logic to determine whether to echo the script or not.

Comment: Billy is right, I am making a form and using PHP to add the information into an SQL Table. But I need error logic so that is why I am trying to use the JQuery to edit the CSS to show the user what they did wrong.

Comment: “Using jQuery in PHP”. Please tell me how you plan to use a client-side framework in a server-side programming language that’s interpreted before sent to the client?

Comment: Would it be more helpful if I showed the form and all the php code so other options can be suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is structured very strangely, and I suspect you're confused about what you should use to do what. Why are you sticking your PHP at the bottom of the page, after all the HTML? That, and the way you talk about your PHP code "getting triggered" in the comments makes me wonder if you understand what exactly PHP does. PHP is a server-side tool for building HTML dynamically. By the time your user sees the page, all your PHP has finished running and can't do anything more until they load the next page. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here, but putting PHP after all your HTML is never the right solution.

If you're putting data into a form, and then reloading the same page with the form data, what you should do is put the bulk of your PHP at the *top* of the page, and then put little bits of PHP interspersed throughout your HTML wherever you want something dynamic. Javascript shouldn't be needed unless you're doing something fancy.

Comment: I am confused on what needs to be done to complete what I am trying to. So I have a form and I want to use PHP to add data into an SQL Table, but I only want it to add the data if there are no errors and once the submit button is pressed. And then for errors I want text to show up under the part that was done wrong so like it the username is already in use, I want text saying that username is already in use to appear under the username input area. I'm going to add all my HTML and PHP so you can better understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `html` tag.  So the page is ignoring the stuff afterward.  Move the `</body>` and `</html>` tags to after your script.  Also you don't need to echo the the scripts.  Unless you are doing some php logic in your script that you are not showing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head />
<body>
    //All my HTML code...

    //Related HTML code
    <div>
        <span class="notFilled" id="notFilled">*Please fill in all the fields.</span>
    </div>

<?php
//All my PHP code...

//Related PHP/JQuery code
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
, '$("#notFilled").css("visibility","visible")'
, '</script>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I put it in there will it trigger on the click of a sumbit button but not in the very beginning of loading the webpage.

Comment: If you want it to trigger on the click of a button, you need to add an event handler to the button and wrap the code in that.  All that putting the script at the bottom does is allow you to not wrap the code in a `$(document).ready()`.  http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I want the PHP to trigger on the click and the JQuery to work if there is an error such as not all the fields are filled or an email is already in use, etc.

Comment: When I put the PHP in the body it runs on the page's loading, not the click of the button?

Comment: The PHP is executed on the server when the user opens the page.  You can't make php execute on the click of a button, it already has executed.  The javascript get executed when the browser renders it, so if you want to have a function run on click, you need to create a function and register an event handler for it (either via `$.click()` or adding an `onClick` attribute.

Comment: There is no way for the PHP to run on a button click?

Comment: PHP is a server side language.  It is executed on the server and the results are sent to the browser.  The browser then renders the html and executes any javascript on the page.  In order to have a php script executed on a button click, you need to make an ajax call to the server and have the php executed there which will then return data to the browser.  The browser does not execute php code.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Comment: If I move the PHP/JQuery to a separate page, then add the action of the form to run the other php document, would that work? Would I be able to have it so visually you see the one with HTML, but have it doing the code of the other PHP page? And if so how would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

your `<script>` is outside the `<html>` tag.. it should be placed before the closing `</body>` tag

Anyway, this is a really dirty code.. Mixin Html, JS and PHP?.. you need to completly separate them. It will save you some headaches

Hope this helps

Comment: If you put the PHP inside the HTML will it still trigger how it currently triggers?

Comment: you can put the php tags wherever you want... before html.. inside the html.. inside any tag i.e. `<a href="<?php echo "hi";?>">` but mixing everything together is a bad idea.. try MVC :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all ..

1) load the jquery.js script in your head....

2) i don,t understand why are you using   when you can  use `<script></script>` and ways... put the <body> and

3)use document.ready function

**updated code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  //load jquery script here
</head>
<body>
 //All my HTML code...

 //Related HTML code
 <div>
    <span class="notFilled" id="notFilled">*Please fill in all the fields.</span>
 </div>
 <?php 
    //all your php code
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#buttonID').click(function(){ //<--updated here
       $("#notFilled").css("visibility","visible");
      });
   });
  </script>;
</body>
```

Comment: The JavaScript is in the PHP because I am using the JavaScript to display error messages to the user.

Comment: How would I call the JavaScript within the PHP then? Also when I put the PHP in the Body it runs it when the page loads, but I want it to run on the click of a button

Comment: then you need to add the click event to the button.. and an id and call od selector.. check out my update

Answer (score 0):

Instead if trying to edit the css, it may be a good idea to use the [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) methods. You can even use transitions to make it look nicer ([.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)...)

In any case, I wouldn't recommend the involving php to load javascript, but at the end of the day, I'm not sure of the context of the script.

Comment: The context is the HTML is contains a form to register to a website. The PHP is used to insert the data into the SQL Table and to trigger the errors if something is wrong. The JQuery is trying to be used to display error messages by changing the visibility of the error to visible when the error occurs. So how would you use the .show() and the .hide() so that it is hidden on the loading of the page but then shows when an error occurs?

Comment: A good way to get it to appear just when the error occurs is having `display: none` in the css and show it with `.show()`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery might not be loaded yet when you are calling the jQuery`.css()` function.

Make sure that the jQuery js file is being loaded before (make sure it appears above) any jQuery function calls.

Comment: I added this on the script: src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, make sure that file is being loaded using your browser's debugger. It must appear above any calls to `.css()`